# Using script display specific revision in google docs

Tags: google-apps-script

In Google App Script I've written some code to list, tag and label revisions using the Google Docs API combined with Google Drive API. I now want to find a way to make the UI show a previous revision (like the built in revision viewer can do), however I can't see an API for this.

Is it possible via a script to make Google Docs (and sheets) show a specific revision of a document?

Answer (score 0):

The [Advanced Drive service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/drive) has the ability to ['List Revisions'](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/drive#listing_revisions). However, you would need to build your own UI to display the change, I believe.

Comment: I've managed to get the list of revisions - as you suggest and build a UI to show them. However I can't get the content associated with each revision for Sheets/Docs - for other file types you can get a 'downloadUrl' but it doesn't seem to work for sheets/docs.

Comment: Having a glance at the API explorer, it seems that for sheets you must download previous revisions of sheets (as you get an export URL that exports previous versions). Perhaps you can fetch the URL and use it to display that in your App, but I'm not certain as I've never played with the revision history API.